# ASWebAuthentication services

Tags: ios, swift, aswebauthenticationsession

We use ASWebAuthenticationSession for SSO handling and have set **prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession** as false before calling start. But when we try to login with safari, it again asks for password. Do I need to add/configure anything other than setting the flag prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession ?

Comment: Any progress with this one? I am facing same issue.

Comment: @Craig. Noting so far.